# how to create time slots in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

I'm trying to create a list of time slots for building an appointment-related app. For example, build-time slots from 8 AM TO 10 PM with a 30-minute gap between each interval. I'm trying to achieve the result using the flutter/dart DateTime class

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime startTime = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 8, 0, 0);
DateTime endTime = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 22, 0, 0);
Duration step = Duration(minutes: 30);

List timeSlots = ['8:30','9:00','9:30']; // this is what I'm trying to achieve (final output)
```

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```dart
void main() {
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  DateTime startTime = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 8, 0, 0);
  DateTime endTime = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 22, 0, 0);
  Duration step = Duration(minutes: 30);
  
  List<String> timeSlots = [];
  
  while(startTime.isBefore(endTime)) {
    
    DateTime timeIncrement = startTime.add(step);
    timeSlots.add(DateFormat.Hm().format(timeIncrement));
    startTime = timeIncrement;
  }
}
```

And if you print it out, you get this output:

```dart
[08:30, 09:00, 09:30, 10:00, 10:30, 11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30, 13:00, 13:30, 14:00, 14:30, 15:00, 15:30, 16:00, 16:30, 17:00, 17:30, 18:00, 18:30, 19:00, 19:30, 20:00, 20:30, 21:00, 21:30, 22:00]
```

Note: I imported the **intl** package (import 'package:intl/intl.dart') so i could do the fomatting.

Comment: Thanks mate! This would work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Making some slight modifications to Roman Jaquez's answer I got this

```
void main() {
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  DateTime startTime =
      DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 0, 0, 0);
  DateTime endTime =
      DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 23, 59, 0);
  Duration step = Duration(minutes: 1);

  List<BidSlot> timeSlots = [];

  while (startTime.isBefore(endTime)) {
    DateTime timeIncrement = startTime.add(step);
    timeSlots.add(BidSlot(
        startTime: DateFormat.Hm().format(timeIncrement),
        endTime: DateFormat.Hm().format(timeIncrement.add(
          Duration(minutes: 1),
        ))));
    startTime = timeIncrement;
  }
  print('timeslots ------------- timeSlots');
  timeSlots.forEach((e) => print('${e.startTime} == ${e.endTime}'));
}

Print result : [00:01 == 00:02, 00:02 == 00:03, 00:03 == 00:04, 00:04 == 00:05, 00:05 == 00:06 … 23:55 == 23:56, 23:56 == 23:57, 23:57 == 23:58, 23:58 == 23:59, 23:59 == 00:00]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
String generateTimeSlots({
  required DateTime startTime,
  required DateTime endTime,
}) {
Duration step = const Duration(minutes: 30);

List<TimeSlot> timeSlots = [];

while (startTime.isBefore(endTime)) {
timeSlots.add(TimeSlot(
    startTime: DateFormat.Hm().format(startTime),
    endTime: DateFormat.Hm().format(startTime.add(
      const Duration(minutes: 30),
    ))));
  DateTime timeIncrement = startTime.add(step);
startTime = timeIncrement;
}

String timings = '';

for (var e in timeSlots) {
  timings += '${e.startTime}-${e.endTime},';
}

  print(timings);
  return timings;
}

class TimeSlot {
  final String startTime;
  final String endTime;

  TimeSlot({required this.startTime, required this.endTime});
}
```